# Modes of Convergence of a particular random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, lebesgue-measure

Let $X_n \sim U([-1/n,1/n])$ be uniform random variables on $[-1/n,1/n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Do the $X_n$ converge, and if yes in what sense?

I think it converges pointwise as for any $x \in [-1/n,1/n]$ you can choose $n > x$ so that $X_n(x)$ is then equal to $0$. Hence $X_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise.

I believe if you take the measure to be the Lebesgue measure. Then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in measure as $\lambda(X_n)=2/n \rightarrow 0$.

Does it converge almost everywhere? Not sure how to attempt to write up a proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we know is the distribution of $X_n$, but not necessarily $X_n(\omega)$ for each $\omega$. For example, if $Y_n=X_n$ on a set of probability $1$, then $Y_n$ is distributed as $X_n$. In particular, we cannot deduce a pointwise result.

Since for almost every $\omega$ and each $n$, $|X_n(\omega)|\leqslant 1/n$, we obtain that $X_n\to 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: And in every $L^p$, including $L^\infty$, and in probability and in distribution.

Comment: So I am wrong about the pointwise case